# How to delete an end of string in a php array?

Tags: php

I have a php array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [2] => JDRAC9_0010-2.jpg
    [3] => JDRAC9_0010-3.jpg
    [4] => JDRAC9_0010-4.jpg
    [5] => JDRAC9_0010-5.jpg
    [6] => JFEAQ4_3473-1.jpg
    [7] => JFEAQ4_3473-2.jpg
    [8] => JFEAQ4_3473-3.jpg
 )
```

and I'd like to have:

```
Array
(
    [2] => JDRAC9_0010
    [3] => JDRAC9_0010
    [4] => JDRAC9_0010
    [5] => JDRAC9_0010
    6] => JFEAQ4_3473
    [7] => JFEAQ4_3473
    [8] => JFEAQ4_3473
 )
```

I've tried for the extension :

```
   $photos2 = array_map(function($e){
        return pathinfo($e, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    }, $photos);
    print_r($photos);
```

How do I delete the -1, -2 as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `explode` each item by `-` and take the first item from results:

```
$photos2 = array_map(function($e){
    return explode('-', $e)[0];
}, $photos);
print_r($photos2);
```

Also, if there are more than one `-` in file name, you can try find the position of last `-` and return a substring from start to this postition:

```
$photos2 = array_map(function($e){
    return substr($e, 0, strrpos($e, '-'));
}, $photos);
print_r($photos2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex way,

```php
$names = array_map(function ($item) {
    preg_match('/[a-zA-Z0-9\_]+/', $item, $out);
    return isset($out[0]) ? $out[0] : null;
}, $photos);
```

Thanks.